Calling functions using the smart contract does not change state
When I call the write function to change the state of the contract, I use the Hedera SDK feature. Although the transaction receipt I receive is successful, the state of the contract does not change.
But I call on Hashcan.io again successfully and it actually works to change the state
Typescript Code
export async function createAuction(_auction: TAuctionCreation, walletInterface: WalletConnectWallet) {
    const {
        name,
        description,
        tokenId,
        tokenAddress,
        startingPrice,
        minBidIncrement,
        endingPrice,
        endingAt,
        receivers,
        percentages
    } = _auction;
    if (!name) throw new Error('Name is required');
    if (!description) throw new Error('Description is required');
    if (!tokenAddress) throw new Error('Token address is required');
    if (!tokenId) throw new Error('Token ID is required');
    if (!startingPrice) throw new Error('Starting price is required');
    if (!minBidIncrement) throw new Error('Minimum bid increment is required');
    if (!endingPrice) throw new Error('Ending price is required');
    if (!endingAt) throw new Error('Ending time is required');

    try {

        const transaction = await new ContractExecuteTransaction()
            .setContractId(appConfig.constants.AUCY_CONTRACT_NFT_AUCTION_MANAGER_ID)
            .setGas(MAX_GAS)
            .setMaxAttempts(MAX_ATTEMPTS)
            .setPayableAmount(new Hbar(100, HbarUnit.Tinybar))
            .setFunction("createAuction", new ContractFunctionParameters()
                .addString(name)
                .addString(description)
                .addAddress(ContractId.fromString(tokenAddress).toSolidityAddress())
                .addInt256(tokenId.toString())
                .addInt256(startingPrice.toString())
                .addInt256(minBidIncrement.toString())
                .addInt256(endingPrice.toString())
                .addInt256(endingAt.toString())
                .addAddressArray(receivers!)
                .addInt16Array(percentages!)
            )
            // .freezeWithSigner(walletInterface.getSigner())
            .freezeWith(client);

        // const sign = await transaction.signWithSigner(walletInterface.getSigner());

        // const txResponse = await sign.executeWithSigner(walletInterface.getSigner());
        const txResponse = await transaction.execute(client);
        console.log('txResponse', txResponse);

        const receipt = await txResponse.getReceipt(client);
        console.log('receipt', receipt);

        return null;
    } catch (error: any) {
        console.error('Error creating auction', error);
        throw new Error(error);
    }

}

Solidity Function
function createAuction(string _name, string _description, address _tokenAddress, uint256 _tokenId, address _topicId, uint256 _startingPrice, uint256 _minBidIncrement, uint256 _endingPrice, uint256 _endingAt, address[] _receivers, uint16[] _percentages) returns (address)

I need everyone's help, please give me a specific solution.
